# OpenCart installation message error

Tags: wamp, opencart

I'm trying to install OpenCart using Wamp server but i got this message error .

> Warning: require_once(d:\wamp\www\opencart\upload\config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in d:\wamp\www\opencart\upload\index.php on line 9

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delete all the files and database and Try to install with fresh download. Seems like files are missing.

Answer (score 0):

In startup.php change:

```
// Error Reporting
   error_reporting(E_ALL);

 to

// Error Reporting
  error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Check in (d:\wamp\www\opencart\upload\config.php) that "config.php" file is present or not. If not then you will have to reinstall opencart again. Let me know ahead.

Answer (score 0):

If You had a fresh download (manual or from GIT) and tried to install, the installation setup at step 2 should check whether it is possible to write to required files/folders. The write access is required to create the `config.php` files (for catalog and for administration).

It is not required to create a blank `empty.php` before installation as there is a blank `config-dist.php` used to be copied into a `config.php` file.

So the only solution needed for this is to allow the write access (either 775 or 777). But when speaking of WAMP (and Windows) there should not be a problem with write access unless You are setting *read-only* permissions for all Your `www` folder...

Answer (score 0):

This is a path issue. Check your path carefully.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**config.php** file is missing.

You need to rename "**config-dist.php**" and "**admin/config-dist.php**" to "**config.php**" respectively

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the answer is in the error message:
"d:\wamp\www\opencart\upload\config.php"
"Permission denied"

Make sure PHP is able to read and write to this file - right click it in Windows and check Properties > Security.

Answer (score 0):

you need to rename the file as config,  no need to rename the file config.php
because already the  PHP extension is available on that file